# If I dissolve 0.1M of CaCl2.2H2O in water, do I get a 0.1M CaCl2 solution?

Tags: solutions, concentration

If I dissolve $\pu{0.1 M}$ of $\ce{CaCl2.2H2O}$ in water, do I get a $\pu{0.1 M}$ $\ce{CaCl2}$ solution?

Comment: @Pastudent - you don't neglect the water of hydration. You should dissolve 0.1 moles of the hydrate in say 750 ml of water and then add water in a volumetric flask to get "exactly" 1.000 liter of solution total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try to be clear. Nobody can dissolve 0.1 M of anything in water. 0.1 M is not an amount. It is a concentration. I think you should replace "M" by "mole".

Second, you must mention the amount of water used to dissolve your product, or the final volume. I think you should rewrite your demand in such a way : "If I dissolve 0.1 mole CaCl2·2H2O in enough water to get a final volume of one liter, do I get a 0.1 M CaCl2 solution?"

And here the answer would be "Yes !"

Comment: Kudos for pointing out the flaw in how the units were specified in the problem statement. Newbies need that sort of clarification to understand how all the terminology fits together.

Comment: At least the title was correct.

Comment: NO ! The title is not correct !! It is impossible to dissolve 0.1 M of anything in water, without specifying the volume of water.  The title and the question are exactly the same series of words !!